# Is there a Random Graph generator Library in Java?

Tags: java, graph

Is there a Graph generation library in Java which generators graphs (of different types) such that
G{n,p} graph chooses each of the possible [n(n-1)]/2 edges with probability p.

The closest I could find was [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/index.html) -Python package for the creation, manipulation, and study of the structure, dynamics, and functions of complex networks.

Well If I cant find anything good I might have to create my own random generator using jGraph or jgraphT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well nevermind
I just used JgraphT to write a function which adds edges based on a probability p for each edge.

Answer (score 1):

http://jung.sourceforge.net/
 i hope it helps

Comment: Jung has several [random graph generators](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/generators/random/package-summary.html). I think you want the Erdos-Renyi.

Answer (score 0):

There are several such generators in [gephi](https://gephi.org/): Erdős–Rényi by default, and many others through additional plugins (Barabasi-Albert, Watts-Strogatz...).